# If you get tears out of love of Allah, is that sign of iman?

Tags: allah, love

If you get tears when you think positively about Allah or you get tears out love for Allah, is that good thing or sign of iman?
I know people get tears when they fear Allah, what about you get tears when you love Allah?

I hope that made sense.

Answer (score -1):

Holy Prophet (SAW) said:

“There are seven whom Allah will shade in His Shade on the Day when there is no shade except His Shade: a just ruler; a youth who grew up in the worship of Allah, the Mighty and Majestic; a man whose heart is attached to the mosques; two men who love each other for Allah’s sake, meeting for that and parting upon that; a man who is called by a woman of beauty and position [for illegal intercourse], but be says: ‘I fear Allah’; a man who gives in charity and hides it, such that his justify hand does not know what his right hand gives in charity; and a man who remembered Allah in private and so his eyes shed tears.”[Al-Bukhaari and Muslim]

Comment: I know above hadith but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Consider elaborating this evidences are not self-explanatory https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/13438